# Is it possible to use vectorization for a conditionnal count of rows in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a Pandas Dataframe with data about calls. Each call has a unique ID and each customer has an ID (but can have multiple Calls). A third column gives a day. For each customer I want to calculate the maximum number of calls made in a period of 7 days.

I have been using the following code to count the number of calls within 7 days of the call on each row:

```
df['ContactsIN7Days'] = df.apply(lambda row: len(df[(df['PersonID']==row['PersonID']) & (abs(df['Day'] - row['Day']) <=7)]), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
CallID  Day PersonID    ContactsIN7Days
6       2   3           2
3       14  2           2
1       8   1           1
5       1   3           2
2       12  2           2
7       100 3           1
```

This works, however this is going to be applied on a big data set. Would there be a way to make this more efficient. Through vectorization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC this is a convoluted, but I think effective solution to your issue. Note that the order of your dataframe is modified as a result, and that your `Day` column is modified to a timedelta dtype:

Starting from your dataframe `df`:

```
   CallID  Day  PersonID
0       6    2         3
1       3   14         2
2       1    8         1
3       5    1         3
4       2   12         2
5       7  100         3
```

Start by modifying `Day` to a timedelta series:

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Day'], unit='d')
```

Then, use [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html), to merge your dataframe with the count of calls by each individual in a period of 7 days. To get this, use `groupby` with a [`pd.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) with a frequency of 7 days:

```
new_df = (pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values(['Day']),
                        df.sort_values(['Day'])
                        .groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Day', freq='7d'), 'PersonID'])
                        .size()
                        .to_frame('ContactsIN7Days')
                        .reset_index(),
                        left_on='Day', right_on='Day',
                        left_by='PersonID', right_by='PersonID',
                        direction='nearest'))
```

Your resulting `new_df` will look like this:

```
   CallID      Day  PersonID  ContactsIN7Days
0       5   1 days         3                2
1       6   2 days         3                2
2       1   8 days         1                1
3       2  12 days         2                2
4       3  14 days         2                2
5       7 100 days         3                1
```